# How do I configure NPM to Trust the firewall issuer for HTTPS proxying?

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate, npm, firewall

I am attempting to use NPM in an environment behind a corporate firewall.  Said firewall intercepts all https traffic and signs it with its' own CA... Is there a way to "trust" this CA so that NPM can actually work?

Comment: I realize that this may be more appropriate to another StackExchange site, but given it is specific to a particular development platform, I felt this was a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is better way to configure npm to trust certificates issued by a specific CA.

```
npm config -g set cafile /path/to/myCA.cert
```

This will add this CA (probably your company's self signed certificate) to the npm's trusted CA's. With this solution, you get the benefit of SSL key validation and adding your own CA entities.

Comment: It's worth noting, that if you're forced through internal proxy, that the cert validation is pretty much meaningless anyway...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997570/185034) provides more detail and example for the `cafile` config property.

Answer (score 6):

*NOTE: This solution should not generally be used, see Josep's answer above as well as [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997570/185034) from comments.  This question and answer were before the cafile options, iirc.  Also, in my case it was behind a corporate proxy that self-signed everything anyway.*

Old/Deprecated answer below.

---

Found the solution... (Ignoring SSL Certs)

```
npm config -g set strict-ssl false
```

Thanks to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/npm-/sf6zrKyrxjU/3Fq8x_DlokwJ) in google groups.

Comment: Warning:  I believe this solution causes npm to accept ANY certificate.  It would be better if there was an option to tell npm to trust only a specific certificate.

Comment: @ScottMarchant fair enough.. or for that matter, being able to add the internal CA chain... that said, the solution above works in the given environment.  I had the same problems with git, and some other, similar issues in the end.