# npm add root CA

Tags: npm, ca

I am looking for a way to add a custom CA to NPM so I can download from a location using said certificate (an internal git-server) without having to nuke all CA-checking with

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Is there any way of achieving this or not? (if not: is there already a defect?)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can point npm to a [`cafile`](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#cafile)

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/cert.pem
```

You can also configure [`ca`](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#ca) string(s) directly.

```
npm config set ca "cert string"
```

[`ca`](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#ca) can be an array of cert strings too. In your `.npmrc`:

```
ca[]="cert 1 base64 string"
ca[]="cert 2 base64 string"
```

The `npm config` commands above will persist the relevant config items to your `~/.npmrc` file:

```
cafile=/path/to/cert.pem
```

***Note***: these CA settings will override the default "real world" certificate authority lookups that npm uses. If you try and use any public npm registries via https that aren't signed by your CA certificate, you will get errors.

So, if you need to support both public https npm registries as well as your own, you could use [curl's Mozilla based CA bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and append your CA cert to the `cacert.pem` file:

```
curl -o ~/.npm.certs.pem https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
cat my-ca-cert.pem >> ~/.npm.certs.pem
npm config set cafile ~/.npm.certs.pem
```

Unfortunately npm's CA bundle is not editable as it's provided in the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h) (thanks [tomekwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2816199/tomekwi)) but [nitzel has provided a generic Node.js method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239954/1318694) to append a certificate via the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable.

***RHEL Note***: If you happen to be using a RHEL based distro and the RHEL packaged nodejs/npm you can use the standard [`update-ca-trust` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000022/1318694) as RedHat points their packages at the system CA's.

Comment: There is no bundle distributed with node – but there seems to be a list of them in the source: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h

Comment: The github based url is deprecated. The new url is now: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Try `NODE_DEBUG=tls,https,http npm -ddd command` check if your http connection has the CA setting and what the TLS handshake is doing

Comment: @Matt I am using `cacerts` from `%jdk%/%jre%/lib/security` of `Java`. It is showing proper path in `.npmrc`. Still error persist about `npm ERR! fatal: unable to access <URL>: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Any idea about this how to solve it??

Comment: @JimitPatel java has it's own keystore format for certs. The certs would need to be [exported with `keytool`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/652916/1318694) for use outside of java.

Comment: @Matt thanks for response. I found out the problem. I was using it in my Android Studio and by default it was using it's embedded Java rather than one which I kept in my environment. :)

Comment: As a sidenote, in case that `npm config set` does not work for you, try adding the `-g` (global) parameter and troubleshoot where do settings come from with `npm config get`.

Answer (score 43):

If [Matts Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997570/5124673) isn't helping you, the following Windows PowerShell way worked for me and the similar approaches for CMD/Unix worked for other users:

###### Windows Powershell

```sh
$env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=path\to\certificate.pem; npm install
```

---

###### DOS / Windows cmd

(pointed out by [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279255/marc) in the comments)

```sh
set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\\path\\to\\certificate.pem
npm install
```

---

###### Linux / Unix / Mac OS

(pointed out by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667301/mike-pennington) & [mread1208](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077069/mread1208) in the comments)

```sh
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/trusted/CA.pem
npm install
```

Comment: How did you specify a windows path with drive? `/path/to` would only work in Linux...

Comment: Gottit: `set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\\bcp\\cafile.pem` (in DOS)

Comment: @Marc PowerShell accepts `/` and ``\`` (and uses `\`` instead of ``\`` to escape characters) *What a struggle to escape `\`` and ``\`` in markdown ._.*

Comment: Am I missing something or isn't this answer much better than the accepted one? I don't want to "override" the default set, and it doesn't sound like the original question does either. I just want to add one cert to the truststore (my company's MITM cert).

Comment: In Linux / Unix / OSX:  `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/trusted/CA.pem` [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160447/667301)

Comment: How do we set the path in windows?
.npmrc
cafile=c:/folder1/folder2/folder3/caCert.pem               or
cafile=/folder3/caCert.pem

npm config set cafile c:/folder1/folder2/folder3/caCert.pem      or
npm config set cafile c:/folder3/caCert.pem

Comment: @user3380358 Use the command lines in my answer. If you want to permanently set it, see the accepted answer from `Matt`. That occasionally didn't work for me, which is why I posted my alternative.

Comment: @MikePennington's answer worked for me on Mac.  I used FireFox to download the .pem file from the URL I was trying to reach.  Then ran `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/downloaded/CA.pem`, and was able to get around the expired certificate issue!

Comment: One extra necessity in my case was to reboot the machine. Or some node.exe process probably, but on my machine not any node.exe process was running, so tried the reboot. (Windows, environment variable set as system variable via system properties, not via cli, but that shouldnt matter...)

Comment: @Michael That sounds odd to me. Maybe `npm` hung up before. Still odd.. however, I'm happy you managed to get it running :) Maybe your comment will help a dev in the future!