# How to add Certificate Authority file in CentOS 7

Tags: ssl-certificate, ca

I am trying to add certificate Authority (CA) file name - `ca.crt` to `/etc/ssl/certs`, for that I followed [this article](https://www.mankier.com/8/update-ca-trust#Source_Configuration).

I copied my `ca.crt` file  to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and run the command below;

```
update-ca-trust extract
```

After that I checked `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt` file, but I didn't find my CA.

I am not able to figure out what may be the problem.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

copy your certificates inside

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

then run the following command

```
update-ca-trust
```

Comment: `update-ca-trust` provides no output that I can discern, so the only way I was able to convince myself that it was actually doing anything was to keep a copy of the original `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` before running the command and diff it with the new one generated after running `update-ca-trust`.

Comment: I used `curl -li https://domain.name` before/after installation to verify. Before installing I had curl: (60) error.

Answer (score 21):

Find `*.pem` file and place it to the `anchors` sub-directory or just simply link the `*.pem` file to there.

```
yum install -y ca-certificates
update-ca-trust force-enable
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/your-cert.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/your-cert.pem
update-ca-trust
```

Comment: `update-ca-trust` doesn't appear to take any arguments. At least not the one provided in CentOS 7.9 (`ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch`). Not sure what `update-ca-trust force-enable` is supposed to do here.

Answer (score 10):

Your CA file must have been in a binary X.509 format instead of Base64 encoding; it needs to be a regular DER or PEM in order for it to be added successfully to the list of trusted CAs on your server.

To proceed, do place your CA file inside your `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/` directory, then run the command line below (you might need sudo privileges based on your settings);

```
# CentOS 7, Red Hat 7, Oracle Linux 7
update-ca-trust
```

Please note that all trust settings available in the `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/` directory are interpreted with a lower priority compared to the ones placed under the `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` directory which may be in the extended BEGIN TRUSTED file format.

For Ubuntu and Debian systems, `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` is the preferred directory for that purpose.

As such, you need to place your CA file within the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` directory, then update the of trusted CAs by running, with sudo privileges where required, the command line below;

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS7 even though my cert was in a text format (ca.crt file containing `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<key>`

Answer (score 4):

QUICK HELP 1: To add a certificate in the simple PEM or DER file formats to the list of CAs trusted on the system:

- add it as a new file to directory /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
- run update-ca-trust extract

QUICK HELP 2: If your certificate is in the extended BEGIN TRUSTED file format (which may contain distrust/blacklist trust flags, or trust flags for usages other than TLS) then:

- add it as a new file to directory /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/
- run update-ca-trust extract

More detail infomation see `man update-ca-trust`

Comment: Your solution is a copy/paste of the file /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/README

Answer (score 3):

Maybe late to the party but in my case it was *RHEL 6.8*:

Copy `certificate.crt` issued by hosting to:

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

Then:

```
update-ca-trust force-enable (ignore not found warnings)
update-ca-trust extract
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Complete instruction is as follow:

1. Extract Private Key from PFX

`openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.pfx -nocerts -out private-key.pem -nodes`

2. Extract Certificate from PFX

`openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.pfx -nokeys -out certificate.pem`

3. install certificate

`yum install -y ca-certificates`,

`cp your-cert.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/your-cert.pem` ,

`update-ca-trust` ,

`update-ca-trust force-enable`

Hope to be useful