# Where i can find the default system certificate used by PHP by deafult?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

In php.ini i have specified to use the cafile of my domain.
This made email from PHP works and also i have no issue on loading my domain.

I have issue when i try to use composer as seems PHP is using the domain certificate who is not able to get validation.

If i remove the openssl ca.file from php.ini email from PHP stop to work but composer work fine.

Maybe i need find where is the system certificate used by PHP when i remove the openssl line than add the certificate content to mine domain certificate, this should solve the issue.

Any idea of where this certificate can be found?
Do you think this will solve the issue?

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7797#issuecomment-440585828

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Still not tried `update-ca-certificates`? If you insist on workarounds, you can set single ini options on php startup. `php -dopenssl.cafile=… composer.phar …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7797#issuecomment-440680491

In centos the position seems to be little bit different
[How to add Certificate Authority in centos7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043442/how-to-add-certificate-authority-in-centos7)

I found it on etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl