# Where does twine look for certificates?

Tags: python, centos7, twine, pypiserver

I have a personal Python repository set up with https and I'm able to upload to it using the following command:

```
twine upload <dist> -r <my_server> --cert <path/to/certfile>
```

However, I'd like to be able to upload without having to explicitly specify the CA cert location.  I believe I've installed the CA cert in the correct location for my system (using  [How to add Certificate Authority in centos7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043442/how-to-add-certificate-authority-in-centos7) as guidance, and verified using wget), but I still have to call out the raw path.

How can I make twine use my alternate CA cert by default?

Comment: Maybe defining it on an env var? From the help: `--cert path           Path to alternate CA bundle (can also be set via
                        TWINE_CERT environment variable).`

Answer (score 5):

Twine depends on Requests, which in turn relies on Certifi (https://certifi.io/, which in fact is extracted from Requests), and Certifi looks and only looks into its own, "*carefully curated collection of Root Certificates*", by default:

```
>>> import certifi

>>> certifi.where()
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

Which ist different from SSL.

You can either set the `TWINE_CERT` or `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to the path of your CA certs, the former will affect Twine only, the latter will affect anything that relies on Requests.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to determine where Python is looking for your CA certs:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.get_default_verify_paths().capath
/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
```

Then put your custom cert in that directory.