# Behind corporate proxy: npm i => self signed certificate in cert chain

Tags: security, npm, certificate

I am behind a corporate proxy and cannot install my dependencies in a jenkins build. npm i yields the error SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN when installing a specific package.

I have looked on stackoverflow and have found subpar workarounds with no explanations. Some workarounds include using http instead of https, or turning off ssl. I am not looking for a workaround.

I would appreciate an explanation of why I am seeing this error and the right way to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788564/npm-add-root-ca

Comment: @JuanPicado, Thank you. That is what I was looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm add root CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788564/npm-add-root-ca)